# Extracting data from over 20,000 text files

Tags: html, wordpress, text, automation, text-extraction

The current situation I've found myself in includes the following:

Creating a site powered by wordpress, I have over 20,000 text files that contain the content I want to post, the problem however is, they also contain other garbage I have no use for, the structure of each one looks somewhat like this

http://bit.ly/1lTBAoN

I've considered the following (Which all seem extremely time consuming and pointless)

- Creating a macro to automatically go to a specified line in the text file, input the CTRL + C & CTRL + V into the wordpress editor and post it via there, this however seems like quite a bit of work, and the macro will have to be running for a while.
- This part is actually kind of funny, I was going to replace a specific line in all 20k text files with an sql statement to insert into the wp_posts table in the database, and then have it replace another line further down that closes the sql statement, I was then going to use the "Find in all files" option in notepad ++ and delete the garbage line by line.
- I was also contemplating whether it would be a wise idea to just import all of the data into an excel spreadsheet (.csv) and just use the csv wordpress plugin to mass upload them.

There must be a simpler way for me to go about doing this, the only part of the text I want to keep are the iframe elements.

Comment: Hi, welcome to [so]. I thought of embedding the code you linked (that's the correct procedure, *we must show our code here*), but I see that it can be simplified **a lot** and, most importantly, anonymized. Looks like you left links and filenames that could identify your site (you changed all to `example.com`, but there's still stuff there).

Comment: More to the point of the problem at hand: there are lots of `<iframes>` in your sample file, do you mean all of them? . . . Also, what's the origin of those text files, are they pure `.html` files in a server? Is there any directory structure?